# A function that is in $C^k_b(\mathbb R)$ but not in $C^{k+1}_b(\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions

Is there an example of a family of functions, index by $k$, that is in $C_b^k(\mathbb R)$ but not in $C_b^{k+1}(\mathbb R)$ for arbitrary $k$?

$C_b^k(\mathbb R)$ is the space of functions with continuous and bounded derivatives up to $k$.

Comment: This should be a duplicate?  But I did not find the previous one.

Comment: Let $f(x) = 0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) = \arctan(x)^{k-1}$ for $x>0$ to get an example with bounded derivatives.

Comment: You may want to know that $C^k(\Bbb R)$ is not the space of functions with bounded derivatives up to $k$, but the space of functions with continuous derivatives up to $k$.

Comment: Doesn't $\arctan$ have bounded derivatives for all $k$ (with the bound increasing with $k$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f$ by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} (1-x^2)^{k+1} & |x|<1\\0 & |x|\ge1
\end{cases}
$$
Then all derivatives of $f$ up to order $k$ are continuous (they are zero at $|x|=1$).
But the $k+1$-st derivative does not exist at $|x|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a continuous function with compact support but not differentiable function $f(x)$ and integrate it $k$ times:

Let  $g_1(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(x) dx$ and define:
$g_i(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} g_{i-1}(x) dx$

Use : [Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem for Continuous Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785383/lebesgues-differentiation-theorem-for-continuous-functions)
to prove that the derivatives exist.

$g_k(x)$ is the required function.

Answer (score 0):

$F (x)=|x|^{\lambda },  ~~k<\lambda<k+1$